# Join two tables and return an extra field in sping-boot-jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables the first represents houses and the second user reviews. A requirement is to return a json object with all the houses + an extra field with the average review. (So instead of returning back the default, ie an array of houses with []reviews, we just return an array of houses with the average user rating).

An Entity with for the houses is

```
 @Entity
@Table(name="houses")
public class House{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;       
    private String description;     
    private BigDecimal price;  
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "unit", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Review> reviews = new HashSet<>();
}
```

The second entity is

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "reviews")
public class Review {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int stars;    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "house_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    @JsonBackReference
    private House house;
}
```

Each entity has a dto as well. My org.springframework.data.jpa.repository repos are pretty simple, the default.

```
public interface UnitRepository extends JpaRepository<House, Long> {
}
```

What code do I need at the repositories to get back a combined result set of houses + average rating with sorting abilities? I also guess that I need a new Dto for the response class.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood your question but to the best of my interpretation what you can do is, generate the average in your dto or entity using an annotated method, as such:

```java
public class HouseDto {
    
    private Long id;    
   
    private String description;     

    private BigDecimal price;  
    
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Review> reviews;

    // constructors

    @JsonProperty("averageRating")
    public Double getAverageRating() {
        if (reviews == null || reviews.isEmpty()) {
           return 0.0;
        }

        return reviews
            .stream()
            .mapToDouble(s -> s.getStars())
            .average()
            .orElse(0.0);
    }

    // getters/setters etc.

}
```

Comment: That could be a solution, however is this possible to get the averateRating directly from the database query in order to have the ability to "sort by rating"? If yes, how.

Comment: @automedwn Yes, it's achievable, but you'll have to write your own query, see: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query#2-jpql 

I'll edit my answer with an example.

Comment: @automedwn I can't figure out a way to do it without adding so much messy boilerplate that you may as well just do the sorting and average star generation programmatically.

Also keep in mind that if you convert your result to JSON and return it, JSON will not retain the sorted order, so the client will have to sort it again.